# User profiles marked DELETED for active AD accounts

Tags: sharepoint-2016

We have a number of our active AD accounts marked for deletion in the SharePoint 2016 User Profile service, roughly half of our people have had their accounts updated with -DELETED- even though their accounts are still active in Active Directory, running a full synchronisation doesn't seem to resolve this.  There aren't any error in the event logs or the ULS logs and there doesn't appear to be any specific connection between the accounts that have been marked in this way.

Why would the User Profile synchronisation process mark an account for deletion when the AD account is still active?